# XSLT new lines not being preserved

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

For some reason my spaces aren't being preserved in my final PDF after xslt. My desired output is:

Static

text **bold.**

Here's my xslt template:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="" />

<xsl:template match="coverPage">
    <fo:block font-size="12pt" color="black" text-align="center">
        <xsl:text>
            Static
            &#xA;
            text
        </xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-size="12pt" color="black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:text>
            bold.
        </xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which is the result you get?

Comment: Static text **bold**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few issues with your XSLT:

1. **there is no need to enclose the text inside `xsl:text` elements**, as those text nodes are not composed only of whitespace characters and therefore will never be stripped (see [Whitespace stripping](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip) for more details)
2. for the same reason, **there is no need to use `xsl:preserve-space` and `xsl:strip-space`**, unless of course you need them for other reasons
3. preserving linefeeds in the transformation from XML to XSL-FO is just the (required) first step, but then you must preserve them during the processing of the XSL-FO file; in order to do this, you must **use the [`linefeed-treatment`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#linefeed-treatment) property**: `linefeed-treatment="preserve"`
4. a literal linefeed is equivalent to a `&#xA;` entity, so in your input you have *3 linefeeds* between "Static" and "text", which will produce two empty lines when preserved; if that's not what you want, you have to **remove some of them**
5. the words "text" and "bold" are inside two different `fo:block` elements, so this means they will always be on different lines; if you want them to be placed one beside the other, **those words must be inside `fo:inline` elements** instead (and there must be an outer `fo:block` to contain them)

---

### A final word of warning

While looking at an FO file *the difference between a preserved linefeed and an ignored one is not immediately apparent*, as it boils down to the presence of the `linefeed-treatment` attribute in an ancestor element (which could be quite far from the text node itself).

Clearer ways to force a line break in a specific position include:

- using different `fo:block` elements, each one containing the text that should create a line (or several ones)

```xml
    <fo:block>Static</fo:block>
    <fo:block>text <fo:inline font-weight="bold">bold.</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

- using an empty `fo:block` where a line break should be

```xml
    <fo:block>
        Static
        <fo:block/>
        text <fo:inline font-weight="bold">bold.</fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
```