# How to escape " &#xD;" or new line special added character in XSLT PDF?

Tags: pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'am using apache FOP to convert XML to PDF using XSL 1.0.

I've xml node

```
<ABC>This is one line&#xD;
  This is second line&#xD;
This is third line</ABC>
```

and I want Output similar as node i.e

```
  This is one line 
  This is second line
  This is third line
```

but it is coming in only one line.
so is there any solution to escape "&#xD" in xsl ? Following code is used to get the value of node.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="ABC" disable-output-escaping="yes"  />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT new lines not being preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802214/xslt-new-lines-not-being-preserved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you are looking for is [`linefeed-treatment`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#linefeed-treatment).

Setting it to the `"preserve"` will have the effect of processing a linefeed-separated text as separate paragraphs, so a block like this one

```
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">A
B
C</fo:block>
```

will produce three lines in the output

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

On way of solving your problem is with analyse string like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="ABC" regex="&#xD;">
            <xsl:matching-substring></xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the fact that we then split on match and only uses nonmatching strings.

Comment: Not sure whether that helps the poster saying "using ... XSL 1.0".

Comment: No that's true it's a bit of a freudian slip.